# Confusing text in SO help center

Tags: bug, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve contains the following text under the "Complete" heading

> Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them. The acid test of the changes they are about to suggest.

What does "The acid test of the changes they are about to suggest." mean? I get what an [acid test](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acid_test) is, but this isn't a sentence. I think this should probably read something like:

> Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them, as an acid test of the changes they are about to suggest.

Or something else grammatical.

Comment: Sounds like it's supposed to be they and some cuts from later. Like "**They** acid test changes they are about to suggest."

Comment: @thegrinner Well, that would have to be "They acid test the changes..." (no "of").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, ok, that was awkward. Among other changes, I've re-worked that line to read,

> Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post.

For future reference, you can suggest changes to that page here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214955/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta/215383#215383

When you're happy with them, ping me or a Stack Overflow moderator and we'll try to work them in.

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks for the fix and the pointer.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?